# Grouping different columns in 1 sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table with messages (simplified):

```
MessageId,
FromUserId,
ToUserId,
Text
```

And want to make a query output as a chat list like this:

```
LastMessageId,
UserId,
Text
```

So basically create a query that groups FromUserId and ToUserId but only if one of these is my own userId.

So I came up with this:

```
SELECT  (MessageId)
      ,(Text)
      ,(FromUserId)
      ,(ToUserId)
  FROM [Messages] a
  inner join (select FromUserId as FromId, ToUserId as ToId, Max(MessageId) as MaxId from Messages where MessageId > 0 group by FromUserId, ToUserId) as b on
  a.MessageId = b.MaxId 
  join users u on FromUserId = u.userId
  where ToUserId = 123 or FromUserId = 123
```

With this I'm half-way there this the output (say 123 is my user id):

```
MessageId, Text, FromUserId, ToUserId
1          bla   123         345
2          bla2  345         123
3          bla3  678         123
4          bla4  123         678
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
MessageId, Text, UserId
2          bla2  345   
4          bla4  678
```

So I omit my own user id and have only the last message of every conversation.

Can this be done in 1 query? Until now I'm just getting all the messages and am processing this via code.

Comment: How do you define "conversation"?  Note that the ordering of ids generally shouldn't be relied upon, in favor of using a date/time/timestamp column instead (this isn't as problematic in what essentially a log, but anywhere "when" could be changed) - ids should be considered valueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE MessageId IN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT
   CASE WHEN m2.MessageId IS NULL THEN m1.MessageId
   WHEN m1.MessageId > m2.MessageId THEN m1.MessageId ELSE m2.MessageId END
   FROM messages m1
   LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON
   (m1.FROMUSERID = m2.ToUserId
   AND m2.FROMUSERID = m1.ToUserId
   AND m1.MessageId != m2.MessageId)
)
-- AND (messages.FROMUSERID = 123 or messages.ToUserId = 123)
```

[***Sqlfiddle Demo***](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1dfbc/21)

Comment: In the end I made something similar (case when), thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that starts by combining the messages table to get one column with `UserId` and the other information.  It then uses the `row_number()` function to find the most recent message for each user and selects that using `segnum = 1`:

```
SELECT MessageId, Text, UserId
FROM (SELECT MessageId, Text, UserId,
             row_number() over (partition by UserId order by MessageId desc) as seqnum
      FROM ((select FromUserId as UserId, MessageId, Text
             Messages m
            ) union all
            (select ToUserId as UserId, MessageId, Text
             Messages m
            )
           ) m
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you want to limit this to one user, you can add `where FromUserId = @X or ToUserId = @X` to each subquery (better to do this before the `union all`).

Comment: Although the OP seems to want multiple rows per-user; he want most-recent per conversation (like how e-mail systems tend to display it, I guess).